Wagtail generates over 1000 error log during the serve of Hompage which shown correctly
I use wagtail 6.3.1 for a bilingual application. Now I established logging despite I had no problem with my pages generated by Wagtail. Still the pages look good, context variables are populated correctly but I get over 1000 lines of log. These log messages complain missing variables.
The missing variables the log refers to even not included in any of my templates or "includes", blocks or inclusive tags.
Here is a small subset of the log:
DEBUG 2024-12-09 20:08:10,251 base 24273 136577802045120 Exception while resolving variable 'settings' in template 'home/home_page.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 883, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 889, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(
                                            ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 899, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
                      ^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'settings'

...

DEBUG 2024-12-09 20:08:10,264 base 24273 136577802045120 Exception while resolving variable 'in_preview_panel' in template 'home/home_page.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 883, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: 'WSGIRequest' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 893, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'in_preview_panel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 899, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
                      ^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'in_preview_panel'

...

DEBUG 2024-12-09 20:08:10,270 base 24273 136577802045120 Exception while resolving variable 'target_blank' in template 'home/home_page.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 883, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: 'StreamChild' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 893, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'StreamChild' object has no attribute 'target_blank'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 899, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
                      ^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'target_blank'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 906, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist(
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [target_blank] in <block link: StructValue({'title': 'Business Insights', 'url': '', 'page_url': <Page: Business Insights>, 'target_blank': False, 'custom_css': '', 'id': ''})>
DEBUG 2024-12-09 20:08:10,272 base 24273 136577802045120 Exception while resolving variable 'target_blank' in template 'home/home_page.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 883, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: 'StreamChild' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 893, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'StreamChild' object has no attribute 'target_blank'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 899, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
                      ^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'target_blank'


From the time I experience this error, I can not log in to wagtail admin. I wrote a dummy custom authentication middleware just to catch what is in the request and what is the content of the POST. Here is what I got:
Login attempt detected
POST data: <QueryDict: {}>
Session: dict_items([])
Response status: 200
Response headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': 'Mon, 09 Dec 2024 19:15:42 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private', 'Vary': 'Cookie', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'}

Sometimes my log shows different kind of erros:
DEBUG 2024-12-09 20:15:30,820 base 25137 138214654346944 Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 313, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 705, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({"tried": tried, "path": new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLPattern 'sitemap.xml'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'django-admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'ai_blog2.wagtailadmin_urls' from '/home/roland/Documents/developments/ai_blog2/ai_blog2/wagtailadmin_urls.py'> (None:None) 'admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'wagtail.documents.urls' from '/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/wagtail/documents/urls.py'> (None:None) 'documents/'>], [<URLPattern 'log-event/' [name='log_event']>], [<URLPattern 'api/search/results/' [name='search_results']>], [<URLPattern 'api/search/tags/' [name='tag_suggestions']>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'en/'>], [<URLPattern '^static/(?P<path>.*)$'>], [<URLPattern '^media/(?P<path>.*)$'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 883, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: 'URLResolver' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 893, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roland/.pyenv/versions/3.12.7/envs/ai_blog2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 899, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
                      ^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name'

I do not use any custom middlewares just temporarily to catch what is going on with the admin.
Any help is appreciated.

The messages you see in the logs are debug output, not errors. When you say "I can not log in to wagtail admin", what specific behaviour are you seeing within the browser?

@gasman From server side what I see that the request.POST is not populated at all. From client side, after clicking sign in, there is nothing happen. I get no errors in the form, no any feedback, simply the same form is shown filled in with my credentials.
The network tab in browser inspestion shows:

admin ->302
login/?next=/admin/ -> 200
admin/ -> 200
No idea what happened because a week ago I could sign in.
Debug log has 154 lines similar like this:
Exception while resolving variable 'value' in template 'wagtailadmin/login.html'.

